# Python subprocess Module - Popen method with -exec in bash find command

Tags: python, bash

I am using the subprocess module in Python (python 2.6) with the Popen method.

What I am trying to achieve:

I am trying to use the following bash command with Popen that will return a match if it finds a file with "stderr" string.

The code:

bash

```
find . -exec grep "stderr" {} +
```

what I am doing in python

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE


command = "find . -exec grep 'stderr' {} +"
stream  = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, shell=True, cwd=dir)
stream_stdout, stream_stderr = stream.communicate()
```

What I get bacK:

It looks to have worked as stream_stdout and stream_stderr return what I suspect,
but I am getting this txt sent to the screen:

```
 find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

Any ideas why?

****EDIT:
I did not have a space between {}+ this is why I was getting the above out. Apologies! ****

Cheers,

Mike

Comment: I can't reproduce your error in python2.6 on Mac OS X. What is the value of your "dir" argument?

Comment: @Noio Is just a string where I want the command to run. In this case it is in a /data area on my linux machine

Comment: This works for me (Python 2.6, Ubuntu)

Comment: @wutz I am using scientific linux 5 :-/. hmmm

Comment: get your find command to work on the cmd line, before you mix things up with Python. Also, per your last edit I think you need `{} \+`.  Probably need a space, but you def need to escape `+`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try making your command a list of arguments:

```
command = "find . -exec grep 'stderr' {} +".split(" ")
```

Edit: Sorry, I didn't realize Popen() could take a string. This answer is not correct.

Comment: This does not work. it works without split, but I get the message sent to the screen above?

Comment: @MWrite Yes, sorry. I was too hasty in posting my answer. I thought Popen() required syntax was similar to exec*(), when in fact it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the subprocess module?

Would this code, [from Mr. Beazley](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators-uk/index.html), do the job?

```
import os
import fnmatch
import re

def gen_find(filepat,top):
    for path, dirlist, filelist in os.walk(top):
        for name in fnmatch.filter(filelist,filepat):
            yield os.path.join(path,name)

def grep(pat,lines):
    patc = re.compile(pat)
    for line in lines:
        if patc.search(line): return True

for f in gen_find("*","."):
    fopen = open(f, 'rb')
    if grep("stderr",fopen.readlines()):
         print f
```

Comment: It doesn't search for `stderr` in the file contents, but in the file names.

Comment: I need it in the files content, but thanks. Popen method works a treat, but I have no idea why this message to the screen?

Comment: @MWright sorry, I didn't realize you wanted to search the contents. If you just want the matching lines, take a look at Mr. Beazley's gen_grep example.